# LINQ TO NHibernate - NHib 2.1.2

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am looking into the possibility of taking on LINQ to NHibernate in the hopes of simplifying some of my criteria queries.

However I've had some difficulty in locating the correct provider. There seem to be two different providers out there, one written by Steve Strong and the other by Ayende Rahien. I'm not really sure which one to go with.

To complicate matters further, there seem to be different providers for different versions of NHibernate. We're currently using NHibernate 2.1.2 and I don't really want to take the risk of using NHib 3 as it looks like it's still at pre-production levels.

Can anyone tell me:

- which is the best provider to use?
- provide a link to download the source?

Comment: NH 3 is about to be released (unofficial: this week). It doesn't make sense to invest in the old, unsupported provider at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on NH2.1.2, Ayende's original NHibernate.Linq provider is your only choice. The binary is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/), but there seems to be some dispute about the source. It should be in the NHContrib project, but it doesn't seem to be quite right.

When 3.0 becomes stable, Steve Strong's new provider should be the default. There's quite a bit of work to go on it at the moment, but work seems to be proceeding apace.

Comment: 3.0 is stable. It does not have to become stable.

Comment: So, I downloaded NH3.0, but no Linq provider. Does one use the 2.1.2 binary?